# What threshold for percentage change is significant?

Tags: statistical-significance

Here is a scenario: The average score on an exam in Yamaha Elementry in year 1 is 75.1%. 200 students took that test in year 1. In year 2, the average score was 76.5%, which comprised of 230 students. Based on this information, how significant was the performance from year 1 to year 2. Thank you.

Comment: This is going to be hard to answer without any context.

Comment: Could you please edit your question to include your comment?

Comment: I've edited the question for better clarity. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whatever threshold you decide is significant.  Statistical significance is a different thing than practical significance.  Even if we granted that we should interpret your question as referring to statistical significance, the answer we would get would not be directly about the significance of the percentages, but instead the proportion of the time we could expect the percentages to be that far apart or more if the underlying percentages in the population was equal.  Moreover, the exact answer we would get would depend partially dictated by the statistical model we used (although most would converge to the same answer).  A threshold $\alpha$ might typically be used on that proportion to indicate whether we think it is abnormal enough to say that it is 'significant'.  However, because we are comparing samples for which we presumably have all values (the average scores at the elementary school at year 1 and 2), then no statistical inference is necessary... and you are left looking at the differences in percentages and asking yourself whether you think those differences are practically significant (probably based in part on what you think you know about the reliability of the exam).

Comment: Just as I thought! Having trending data would make it easy to infer other catalysts such as seasonality and other shocks into determining what threshold is significant enough. Thanks for the feedback.